# RSA algorithm in Java : How works getEncoded method on java.security.Key interface?

Tags: java, rsa, public-key, asn.1

I would like to be more familiar with the RSA algorithm and I have made small project for that. Actually everithing works fine, I can encrypt and decrypt a message correctly but I don't know if my key generation is performed correctly (my objective is to obtain a public key with a byte array representation that I can export for other parts).

Here comes how my keys are generated:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN"); 

random.nextBytes(new byte[128]);

keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

byte[] publicKeyEncoded  = pubKey.getEncoded();
byte[] privateKeyEncoded = privKey.getEncoded();
```

My question is about the getEncoded method, each time my program is executed a new key pair seems to be generated (according my trace) but when I call this method I have still the same value, it seems fixed. The value is changed when the method is called a second times and is changed each times that I call it in my program, but if a new execution is performed, the first value is the same as first value of the previous execution event if the keys differs.

According the documentation it seems that it "Returns the key in its primary encoding format ...", I have checked my key format, it is X.509, but there is nothing about the described behavior.

Can you please give me more details about that ?

Comment: What if you add something like `System.out.println("Public Key: " + Hex.toHexString(pubKey.getEncoded()));` to your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the code snippet you provided in a standalone java program. Every time I call it, a new different key is generated. If your code always generate the same sequence of key it means that the random number generator produces the same sequence of number.

SHA1PRNG is a PRNG, it means that the sequence of number produced depends on a seed. If the PRGN is seeded twice with the same seed, it will produce the same sequence of numbers. The seed is set as follows:

- by calling `setSeed(byte[])` on `SecureRandom`
- the first `next`/`nextBytes` is called **and `setSeed` has not been previously called** the PRGN is seeded with a secure mechanism provided by the underlying OS.

Since the code you posted here does not call `setSeed`, the `SecureRandom` object should be properly seeded with some true random value.

My suggestions:

1. Are you sure that you do not call `setSeed` (with the same seed value)? This could explain this behavour. Note also that the key encoding provided by `getEncoded()` always starts with the same byte sequence `30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d00`
2. Try to use `random = new SecureRandom()`. It will use the default `SecureRandom` implementation for your platform (For windows as far as I known it is the SHA1PRNG implementation but Linux and MaxOSX are using another implementation)

Comment: Hi Jcs, thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused now because it works today with my code snippet.I tried yesterday with a `random = new SecureRandom()` but i had the effect previsously described, it's why I have tried something more complex. I have tried also with `new SecureRandom(byte[])` with a string converted in byte array but I had the same result. The only difference between yesterday and today is just that my computer was shutdown and restarted, it make me crazy.

Comment: "I'm a bit confused now because it works today with my code snippet...." - +1 for that :)